# Manually start session with specific id / transitioning session cookie between domains

Tags: session, cakephp, cookies

My host requires me to use a different domain for SSL secured access (shared SSL), so I need to transition the user session between two domains. One part of the page lives at `http://example.com`, while the SSL'd part is at `https://example.hosting.com`. As such I can't set a domain-spanning cookie.

What I'm trying to do is to transition the session id over and re-set the cookie like this:

- `http://example.com/normal/page`, user clicks link to secure area and goes to:
- `http://example.com/secure/page`, which causes a redirect to:
- `https://example.hosting.com/secure/page?sess=ikub...`, which resurrects the session and sets a new cookie valid for the domain, then redirects to:
- `https://example.hosting.com/secure/page`

This works up to the point where the session should be resurrected. I'm doing:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    ...
    $this->Session->id($_GET['sess']);
    $this->Session->activate();
    ...
}
```

As far as I can tell this *should* start the session with the given ID. It actually generates a new session ID though and this session is empty, the data is not restored.

This is on CakePHP 1.2.4. Do I need to do something else, or is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `Configure::write('Security.level')` is set to `medium` or higher, `session.referer_check` is implicitly activated, which makes the whole thing fail. Setting the security level to `low` (or using a custom session configuration) makes everything work as it should.

There went about 5 hours of debugging... ( -_-;;)

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to use the Cake file sessions and copy the file over, and then perhaps try and start a new session with that phpsessid, although I'm not even sure if that would actually work or not :)

Comment: Sounds like too much of a hassle and possibly more error prone than the current system. Thanks for the input though. :)

Answer (score 0):

With Cake 2.6.1 -- This is what worked for me.

```
    $this->Session->id("tfvjv43hjmsnjkh0v3ss539uq7"); // add session id you want to set
    $this->Session->id();
    $this->Session->read("key"); // hhoorray worked :)
```

with SessionComponent id() function needs to be called twice once with session id to set session_id(); and second time to start cake session. 
First call does not really start the session ... I dont know how Cake Guys missed it .....

Upvote if this works for you.

Comment: At least ... Have a courtesy to comment the reason why you downvote an answer ??